# Android Studio App not working in new android version

Tags: java, android, android-studio, apk

I created an application, it works in older android version  (Min API is 10), but when i install it in other device (Android 4.4.2) the app doesn't work, i receive the 'App not responding' screen. Any help?

**The app Crash when i select a position in menu, which should open a new activity...**

Thanks , anyway

-Edit (Error msg) -

```
07-20 16:55:26.766  22142-22142/? E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.desenvolvimento.sqlteste, PID: 22142
android.content.ActivityNotFoundException: Unable to find explicit activity class {com.example.desenvolvimento.sqlteste/com.example.desenvolvimento.sqlteste.LoginActivity}; have you declared this activity in your AndroidManifest.xml?
        at android.app.Instrumentation.checkStartActivityResult(Instrumentation.java:1852)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.execStartActivity(Instrumentation.java:1552)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3746)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivityForResult(Activity.java:3707)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:4027)
        at android.app.Activity.startActivity(Activity.java:3989)
        at com.example.desenvolvimento.sqlteste.MainActivity$1.onItemClick(MainActivity.java:33)
        at android.widget.AdapterView.performItemClick(AdapterView.java:300)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.performItemClick(AbsListView.java:1143)
        at android.widget.AbsListView$PerformClick.run(AbsListView.java:3044)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchUp(AbsListView.java:3845)
        at android.widget.AbsListView.onTouchEvent(AbsListView.java:3617)
        at android.view.View.dispatchTouchEvent(View.java:8393)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2426)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2158)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2432)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2172)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2432)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2172)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2432)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2172)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTransformedTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2432)
        at android.view.ViewGroup.dispatchTouchEvent(ViewGroup.java:2172)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2314)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow.superDispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:1692)
        at android.app.Activity.dispatchTouchEvent(Activity.java:2749)
        at com.android.internal.policy.impl.PhoneWindow$DecorView.dispatchTouchEvent(PhoneWindow.java:2275)
        at android.view.View.dispatchPointerEvent(View.java:8583)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.processPointerEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:4091)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$ViewPostImeInputStage.onProcess(ViewRootImpl.java:3957)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3509)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3562)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3528)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3638)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3536)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$AsyncInputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3695)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3509)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.onDeliverToNext(ViewRootImpl.java:3562)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.forward(ViewRootImpl.java:3528)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.apply(ViewRootImpl.java:3536)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$InputStage.deliver(ViewRootImpl.java:3509)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.deliverInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5806)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.doProcessInputEvents(ViewRootImpl.java:5745)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl.enqueueInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5716)
        at android.view.ViewRootImpl$WindowInputEventReceiver.onInputEvent(ViewRootImpl.java:5896)
        at android.view.InputEventReceiver.dispatchInputEvent(InputEventReceiver.java:192)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.nativePollOnce(Native Method)
        at android.os.MessageQueue.next(MessageQueue.java:143)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:122)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.refl
```

-New logcat

```
07-20 17:22:47.931  26650-26650/? E/AndroidRuntime? FATAL EXCEPTION: main
Process: com.example.desenvolvimento.sqlteste, PID: 26650
java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.example.desenvolvimento.sqlteste/com.example.desenvolvimento.sqlteste.LoginActivity}: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2314)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2388)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:148)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1292)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
 Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference
        at com.example.desenvolvimento.sqlteste.LoginActivity.setupActionBar(LoginActivity.java:120)
        at com.example.desenvolvimento.sqlteste.LoginActivity.onCreate(LoginActivity.java:35)
        at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5953)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1128)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2267)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2388)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$800(ActivityThread.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1292)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:102)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5312)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:901)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:696)
```

Comment: Post more details about your code and also logcat output for when the crash happens!

Comment: This is the problem, i can't see the logcat 'cause my device USB isn't working :/

Comment: At what point does the app crash? What is your app trying to do? Give me something to work with.

Comment: Make an emulator running 4.4.2 and give logcat info

Comment: No code? No Exception? No details? Looks like another closed question.

Comment: This is not a Android Studio issue. Your MainActivity does not assign as StartActivity. I mean there is no StartActivity in your program.

Comment: @MetehanToksoy It works in older android and, with start activity you mean this ? protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

Comment: please add the `Login activity` codes instead of :  `NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.app.ActionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(boolean)' on a null object reference`

Comment: Gustavo Henrique did you initialize the menu?

Answer (score 1):

You need to declare `com.example.desenvolvimento.sqlteste.LoginActivity` properly in your `AndroidManifest.xml`. As you are did not supply any code, this is the most specific answer to give.

See the [Android Manifest documentation for `activity`](http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/manifest/activity-element.html).

Also, the next step is to analyze why line 120 in `LoginActivity` is throwing a `NullPointerException` (as per your exception log).

Comment: Which part of the code you want me to show? (I declared the acitvities)

Comment: Please mention it; this only solve the problem number one: `Unable to find explicit activity class`

Comment: @GustavoHenrique I think that the real problem is the at line 120 in `LoginActivity.java`, as this is where the `NullPointerException` is raised, preventing `onCreate()` to succeed.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add your new activity to the AndroidManifest.xml file